# find first of documents for each distinct values for one field

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

With a collection of documents with fields `field1`, `field2`, `field3` and so on, I need to find

1. distinct values for `field3`
2. for each distinct value of `field3`, need to get the first document with each distinct value in `field3`

For # 1, I could do `db.myCollection.distinct("field3")`

How do I go about #2 ?

**Sample Collection:**

```
[
    { "field1": 11, "field2": "toyota", "field3": "camry" },
    { "field1": 22, "field2": "toyota", "field3": "corolla" },
    { "field1": 33, "field2": "toyota", "field3": "camry" },
    { "field1": 44, "field2": "honda", "field3": "accord" },
    { "field1": 55, "field2": "honda", "field3": "accord" },
    { "field1": 66, "field2": "honda", "field3": "city" }
]
```

**Desired result:**

```
[
    { "field1": 11, "field2": "toyota", "field3": "camry" },
    { "field1": 22, "field2": "toyota", "field3": "corolla" },
    { "field1": 44, "field2": "honda", "field3": "accord" },
    { "field1": 66, "field2": "honda", "field3": "city" }
]
```

Comment: What does "first" mean in the context of your collection? Do these documents have a natural ordering?

Comment: first in the sense as equivalent to limit 1

Comment: As I understand you have field with possible values (field1, field2, and 
e.t.c).
So you can use  this syntax db.myCollection.distinct("youDistinctFieldName"). Check out the official documentation
 https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/

Comment: So, any document with from the subset of documents will do? Does this selection need to be stable

Comment: @Dancrumb - yes, any is fine.

Comment: @chridam - added sample documents and output

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to run an aggregate operation that groups all the documents by `field3` and use the **[`$first`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/#grp._S_first)** accumulator with the **[`$$ROOT`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/aggregation-variables/#variable.ROOT)** system variable to bring the first document, something like the following:

```
db.myCollection.aggregate([
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$field3",
            "doc": { "$first": "$$ROOT" }
        }
    }
])
```

or for an exact output:

```
db.myCollection.aggregate([
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$field3",
            "field1": { "$first": "$field1" },
            "field2": { "$first": "$field2" }
        }
    },
    {
        "$project": {
            "_id": 0,
            "field3": "$_id",
            "field2": 1,
            "field1": 1
        }
    }
])
```

Answer (score 2):

Aggregation groups records according to distinct values of field using $group aggregation operator

According to above mentioned description please try executing following query in MongoDB shell

```
db.myCollection.aggregate(

  // Pipeline
  [
    // Stage 1
    {
      $group: {
        _id:{field3:'$field3'},
        data:{$first:'$$ROOT'}
      }
    }

  ]


);
```

In above mentioned query data from the first document for each group is being fetched through use of [$first](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/#grp._S_first) aggregation operator and **$$ROOT** refers to document currently being processed through aggregation operation

Answer (score 0):

chridam answer is correct but if you do not want to write all the fields manually you can try this.

```
db.myCollection.aggregate([
    {
        $group: {
            "_id": "$field3",
            "data": { "$first": "$$ROOT" }
        }
    },
    {   
        $replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$data" } 
    }
])
```